# Multiple datanodes on a single machine in hadoop2.7.1

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am working on hadoop hdfs 2.7.1. I have set up a single node cluster having one datanode. But now i need to set up three datanodes on the same machine. I tried using various methods available on the internet but am unable to start the hadoop cluster having three datanodes on the same machine. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a multi-node cluster on a single machine using Docker containers. The guys at SequenceIQ, a company that was recently acquired by Hortonworks, even prepared Docker images that you can download. See here:

http://blog.sequenceiq.com/blog/2014/06/19/multinode-hadoop-cluster-on-docker/